# Select a value from a 1 DataFrame , based on conditions from 2nd DataFrame and paste this value a new column in the 1st Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Kinda new to Python and this is what I need to do

There are 2 DataFrame's X and Y as follows:
[DataFrame X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSJsV.png)

[DataFrame Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSQuF.png)

I need to fill up the survey answers in DataFrame Y, on the condition that the row chosen from DataFrame X['File Name'] == Y['Survey form name'] and the column to be selected from the X DataFrame will be that of the corresponding row of Y['Questions']. This value then has to be appended to the Y['Survey Answers']

Thank You,
Yash

Comment: Have you already tried something? Then please post it.

Answer (score 0):

#### keeping Cols of Y df into list

`cols = Y.columns.to_list()`

#### merging both dfs

`merged_data = pd.merge(X, Y, left_on='File Name', right_on='Survey form name')`

#### copying survery questions on survey answers

`merged_data['Survey Answers'] = merged_data['Questions']`

#### back to Y df

`Y = merged_data[cols]`

Comment: Hi user14613954, I'm trying to understand the logic of the code but I think what this achieves is that finally the  'Questions' are copied onto the 'Survey answers' which is not the requirement here.
To explain the requirement here, considering row 0 in data frame Y the corresponding value in column ' Survey form name' => sales head or equivalent should be looked in dataframe X 'File Name' and than again for row 0 the Y['Question'] value should be looked up in the columns of dataframe X. This single cell value in the X Dataframe should be copied to row 0 of Y['Survey answer']

Comment: Pl explain this portion with example - than again for row 0 the Y['Question'] value should be looked up in the columns of dataframe X. This single cell value in the X Dataframe should be copied to row 0 of Y['Survey answer'].  Row 0 of Y['Question'] is 'What kind of mechanism .....qualify', this value has to be searched in columns of X df and then what and from where to pick the value for Survey Answers ? I'm confused, sorry

Comment: I understand this is a bit confusing, to simplify things => The following should be iterated for each row of the Y Dataframe: 
Please consider the 1st row of Y df for this example, The value for 'Survey form name' should match the 'File Name' in X df (this will select the row in X) and the value of 'Questions' in Y df should match with column header in X Dataframe (this will select the column in X Dataframe). Now for these selected rows and columns in X df, the intersected cell value needs to be copied in the Y data frame in 'Survey answers'.